# How can I update chrome and chromedriver on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pythonanywhere

I have the latest python, selenium and chrome versions installed on my Mac. I created a script in python with selenium and headless setup, and it ran successfully locally.

When I upload the file to PythonAnywhere and ran the code, the website that I'm interacting with is not working properly. I got the result: UnavailableUnavailable.

My headless setup is:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=pt_BR')
chrome_options.add_argument('--414,900')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

How can I update Chrome and chromedriver on PythonAnywhere?

I tried to update selenium, but it did not work at all, so I went back to version 4.7.2

Comment: do you have a paid PA account? Or if on free tier, is the website you're trying to access whitelisted?

Comment: Update the question  with the complete error stacktrace.